# presenting a view controller cause crash in iOS7 only

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this crash on device only, not on simulator .

I have a view controller,called `main`, in which is the root view:

```
  delegate.window.rootViewController=mainV;
```

This view A , has a container that loads another view controller into it .

later on, i would like to present some view controller to show some hint, and i am doing it by presenting it from view controller A , so it should be above A (and its container) :

```
self.ins=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InstructionViewiPhone"];
 self.ins.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[ self.ins setDelegate:self];
[self presentViewController: self.ins animated:YES completion:^(void)
 {}];
```

it works great but when i am trying to dismiss it, i get a crash :

```
 Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged
```

I guess it has to do with the fact that i have a container with a controller in it on A - that tries to present another view .

I would like to keep this hierarchy ,because it fit best to the design,the container change the controllers,and there are some instruction above all of them. how would i prevent this problem ?

I have tried this :

```
  [self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:self.ins animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Which results in another crash,with same message .
Its not happens in simulator (why? is it because its `iOS7` on the device ? )

**EDIT :**

If i dont load anything to the container in view A , it works great. his problem occurs when the presented is above the container .

Comment: are you re-presenting the old view controller instead of dismissing the new one?

Comment: I am not sure i got you. I have view controller A , he is alive always. he also have a container view. than this A present another view. thats it. when i remove that presented view, i get the crash .

Comment: How are you dismissing the presented controller? there's nothing about this scenario that should cause a crash. It's perfectly fine to present a controller over a container controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem,

What happens is that when you present a view controller, that inside this view, there is a container view ,that loads its own view controller, you have a detached controller , thats something iOS7 is not accept ,but iOS8 does .